# Why template Element directive is not working correctly with Expression in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I working on angularjs+rickshaw. I made simple example from [Angularjs+Rickshaw](http://tagtree.io/d3-with-rickshaw-and-angular). They are making ufo sighing. I made the same example.

```
<h3>UFO sightings in 2008 </h3>                   
   <div ng-repeat="sighting in sightings">
    {{sighting.reportedAt.$date}}
   </div>
<rickshaw-chart></richshaw-chart>
```

Following is working model. [Plunker working Model](http://plnkr.co/edit/lZGM3MkzpHusj5UXlyZU?p=preview).  Directive is printing `this is the rickshawChart directive' But this statement is **replaced by List of UFO** with in second. **Why this is happing like that**

Second if I change the position of `<rickshaw-chart></richshaw-chart>` then It will will print only statement but not show the list. **Why this is happing like that**

```
 <h3>UFO sightings in 2008 </h3> 
   <rickshaw-chart></richshaw-chart>                  
   <div ng-repeat="sighting in sightings">
    {{sighting.reportedAt.$date}}
   </div>
```

See the demo [Not working correcly](http://plnkr.co/edit/LvdpWhkfX0hITOjdOfoS?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your element closing tag

```
</richshaw-chart>
```

Should be

```
</rickshaw-chart>
```

Angular is not finding the proper closing tag and therefore not able to compile the dom correctly. The second demo works fine with this corrected

Answer (score 0):

In the first your directive is not replaced it is still there but it has been pushed to the bottom of the page when your JSON is loaded. Th delay is just the time it takes for you `$http` call to complete.